# How to settings the routers

Tags: ember.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('login', {path: '/'});
  this.route('signup');
  this.route('forgot-password');
  this.route('main'); 
});
```

I have the follow problem, when I use '/login' y I try manually to put /main this won't will redirect to me to '/login'

I wanna control the access because a I can navigate on all my templates if I write it into the search box

Comment: Why if I have this  `this.route('login', {path: '/'});` and I going to `http://localhost:4200/login` there is an error **Uncaught #<UnrecognizedURLError>**

Comment: Because you're specifying that the `login` route can be found at `/`.  If you remove the `path` specification, it'll default to `/login`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the guides:

> If you want to redirect from one route to another, you can do the transition in the beforeModel hook of your route handler.

http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/routing/redirection/#toc_before-the-model-is-known

In your case, if you want to automatically make visiting `/` redirect to `/login`:

```js
// app/router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('login');
});

// app/routes/index.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    this.transitionTo('login');
  }
});
```